# Using unique identifier in MongoDB with different name

Tags: mongodb

I'm going to set up my first Mongo DB collection which will use its own identifier for the customers (the tax id). I understand I can provide myself unique indexes to my Collections, however is it possible to name it differently (instead of "_id" ) ? If so, will I get automatic index creation, or should I create them explicitly ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/).

You can run something like `db.accounts.ensureIndex( { "tax-id": 1 }, { unique: true } )`.